# one timer with multiple updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, updatepanel

have to `updatePanels` like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

i want to have one timer that update the inner `updatePanel` without Update outer `updatePanel`.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find:)
we changed outer `updatePanle` property `Updatemod` to `Conditional`.

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdatePanel` has a method called `Update()`. When your timer hits whatever criteria you need to meet, you then call:

`UpdatePanel4.Update();`

to update the inner `UpdatePanel`

Comment: i did, i also gave the logic you need to follow. try writing some code out, if you run into problems let us know.